# How can I make my newsletter form success message consistently display after clicking send?

Tags: python, django, ajax

[Newsletter form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iGuR.png)
[Console shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl9Kh.png)

After clicking send button, success message shows and email gets saved in database but after the message disappears and I click send again, the success message doesn't show but the data gets sent to database

Also I have set fadeOut time to 2 seconds and during that 2 seconds, the message shows everytime I click send but the message won't show up after it disappears

How can I make the message show even after the message disappears? Help!!!

This is my ajax code:

```
$("#newsletter_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'newsletter' %}",
        data: serializedData,

        success: function(response){
            $("#newsletter_msg").append(
                        `${response.message}`
            ).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow')
        },

        error: function(response){
            $("#newsletter_msg").append(
                `${response.responseJSON.message}`
            ).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow')
        },
    });
});
```